# Selenium switch tab in chromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a program to switch tab in Chrome Driver.

I use this code

```
 for(String winHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
```

or

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

but not work. Is Someone knows the way how to solve it?

Comment: tabs are the same thing as windows, in browser terms.  that's all a tab is; a new browser window presented differently.  you switch tabs by using the method you mentioned here: `driver.switchTo().window(...)`

Answer (score 0):

tabs are the same thing as windows in browser terms, and Selenium terms.  that's all a tab is; a new browser window presented differently.

you switch tabs by using the method you mentioned here:

```
driver.switchTo().window(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the tab to exist. If tab exists then you can switch to it.